# Ajax Call error, Not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Following is code for calling ajax as well as php which is not working please help me. It gives 500 error i don't know why. I have also used $ instead of jQuery and jquery.min.js is also there.

```
jQuery.ajax({

        url: 'http://domain.com/adminer/validate.php',
        method    : 'post',
        data    : {email:emailField.value},
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function(data){
            if(data=="1")
            {
                alert('Already exists');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert('available');
                return false;
            }
        }
});
```

Here is the php code to get email details and reruns the message 1.The php code is working fine but here is something misstate which will be gives 500 error which is display into console.

```
if($_POST['email'])
{       
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","uname","pass","dbname");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }       
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM master_user where email='".$_POST['email']."'");
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
        if($row_cnt > 0){               
            echo "1"; exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "2"; exit;
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: There may be some error in your server side code. Can you run the php code without the ajax ?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: A 500 error in the browser means "Read your server logs to find out what the error is".

Comment: Yes, Php code is running without ajax.

Comment: I will give me error just after the ajax call, it will display RED path in the console as path is correct.

Comment: Is here any mistake into the code ?

Comment: May be in your php `if` statement. `if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != "")`

Comment: No Chin it's not working so far. still it is give me RED into console,

Comment: Here is the text display into RED console and it shows me jquery.min.js path at right side of console.
"POST http://domain.com/adminer/validate.php"   15ms

Comment: may be error at "data    : {email:" try data:{"email":""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as per below.I have not tested but ,I think its working fine.

jQuery.ajax({

```
    url: 'http://domain.com/adminer/validate.php?email='+emailField.value,
    method    : 'post',
    success : function(data){
        if(data=="1")
        {
            alert('Already exists');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('available');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

});